# matlab - unfixed dimension matrix, set value to multiple fields of struct at once, avoid loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, struct, matrix-storage

I have 2 (not very small) 3-dimension structs with matrices as fields:

```
sz1 = 200;
sz2 = 9;
sz3 = [20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120]
% actually the structs have 12 fields, each has size 200x9x5120
mat.p1(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = uint8(0);
mat.p2(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = uint8(0);
mat.p3(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = 0;
mat.p4(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = 0;
old_mat.p1(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = uint8(0);
old_mat.p2(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = uint8(0);
old_mat.p3(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = 0;
old_mat.p4(sz1, sz2, sz3(sz2)) = 0;
```

And i need to write a `reset` function, where i will re-assign the values to 3 of 4 (actually 10 of 12) fields in both matrices as follows:

```
for i = 1:sz1
  for j = 1:sz2
    for k = 1:sz3(j)
      mat.p1(i,j,k) = uint8(255);
      mat.p3(i,j,k) = -1;
      mat.p4(i,j,k) = 0.01;
      old_mat.p1(i,j,k) = uint8(255);
      old_mat.p3(i,j,k) = -1;
      old_mat.p4(i,j,k) = 0.01;
    end
  end
end
```

Note that actually what i need in the matrices is the same as the `reset` function, means i only need the 5120th index of the 3rd-dimension when 2nd-dimension is 9, if 2nd-dimension = 4, i only need up to 160 indices at 3rd-dimension etc.

The questions are:

1. Is there anyway to assign values to the fields at the same time (not 1 line 1 field) since i actually have to do with 10 fields?
2. Is there anyway to avoid the for-loops? I tried like this:

   ```
   mat.p1(:) = uint8(255);
   mat.p3(:) = -1;
   mat.p4(:) = 0.01;
   old_mat.p1(:) = uint8(255);
   old_mat.p3(:) = -1;
   old_mat.p4(:) = 0.01;
   ```

   but here all the matrices are filled with max 3rd-dimension = 5120 so i expect someone can show me how to use the vectorizing function like `arrayfun, bsxfun, cellfun etc.`, which can apply for just the "half-cubic" like the for-loops above.

UPDATE:
Thanks horchler for the video, it seems the problem with big size (in bytes) of the matrices is solved when i change the matrix of struct to a struct with matrices as fields. This also clears the timing problem even with nested for-loops. So i updated the questions and the input as well, please see above.

Comment: You might find [this video from The MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/04/22/matlab-basics-array-of-structures-vs-structures-of-arrays/) helpful.

Comment: thanks, i updated the questions. The question about assigning values to multiple fields at once still remains though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that using a structure of arrays will work better for you here. You should be able to allocate using `zeros` just as if `mat.p1`, `mat.p2`, etc. were regular arrays. I'd do something like this (note that you didn't indicate any values for `mat.p2`) using a single `for` loop:

```
sz1 = 200;
sz2 = 9;
sz3 = [20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120];
% Be careful with this form of pre-allocation if your sz arrays change
% Clear your struct or make sure to use the code in a function 
mat.p1(sz1,sz2,sz3(sz2)) = uint8(0);
mat.p3(sz1,sz2,sz3(sz2)) = 0;
mat.p4(sz1,sz2,sz3(sz2)) = 0;
for i = 1:sz2
    mat.p1(:,i,1:sz3(i)) = uint8(255);
    mat.p3(:,i,1:sz3(i)) = -1;
    mat.p4(:,i,1:sz3(i)) = 0.01;
end
old_mat.p1 = mat.p1;
old_mat.p3 = mat.p3;
old_mat.p4 = mat.p4;
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
sz1 = 200;
sz2 = 9;
sz3 = [20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120];
mat = struct('p1',zeros(sz1,sz2,sz3(sz2),'uint8'),...
             'p3',zeros(sz1,sz2,sz3(sz2)),...
             'p4',zeros(sz1,sz2,sz3(sz2)));
for i = 1:sz2
    mat.p1(:,i,1:sz3(i)) = uint8(255);
    mat.p3(:,i,1:sz3(i)) = -1;
    mat.p4(:,i,1:sz3(i)) = 0.01;
end
old_mat = struct('p1',mat.p1,'p3',mat.p3,'p4',mat.p4);
```

Comment: i didnt indicate any value for `p2` since i want to imitate my real problem, in which i have to reassign values to 10 fields out of 12 fields total (here 3 of 4). And in that case, both `mat` and `old_mat` need 10 lines, so i want a 1-line-code to assign values to multiple fields at once. It's also why i want vertorizing with i.e `arrayfun` or `bsxfun` than indexing like you did. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Why is one line of code important to you? Unless you're using a very old version of Matlab, I think you'll find that a single `for` loop is both more readable and faster in this case. `arrayfun`, just a loop in disguise, definitely won't be faster (it rarely is) and `bsxfun` makes little sense here. Two dimensions of your arrays are already vectorized in the `for` loop and JIT compilation likely helps you as well. It may be possible to use `reshape` and/or `repmat` in some way.

Comment: you are right, the speed problem was fully solved by using struct of arrays and indexing. The question about 1-line code and vectorizing functions is just my own interest (i'm not good at using them), and i actually find something like `s = setsomefields(s, [some_fields], [some_val])` more readable .